# Can't see my POST request on server (doesn't appear on my server index.php page even if I refresh it)

Tags: php, python, http, post

I am trying with a very simple example where my data is temperature, and I want it to be seen on my website index.php page after I successfully POST data from my python code.

Here's my simple index.php code;

```
    <?php

       echo 'Hello ' . $_POST["temp1"] . '!';
       $data=$_POST["temp1"];
    ?>

  <html>
    <head>
       <title>Sensor Data</title>
    </head>
  <body>
   <h1>HELLO </h1>

  <?php 
     printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%s </td></tr>", $data)
  ?>

 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sending a POST request using requests from python,

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://www.********.com", data={"temp1":"Anum"})
print(r.text)
```

My POST request works perfect, and I can see the result of print(r.text) as "Hello: Anum! ", but it actually doesn't appear on my server index.php page even if I refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $data=$_POST["name"];
```

Not familiar with Python interfacing with PHP but shouldn't it be like that?(Below)

```
   $data=$_POST["temp1"];
```

Comment: Ops that was a writing mistake, I've corrected it. Thanks @Nicky,

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing storing the data on the server. Every time you refresh the page (which includes when you POST to it in python) the script will run from the start. It works when you POST to it in python because it has the value that you send to it when it renders (ie, executes the php code), but when the browser requests it and doesn't send the POST data then the variables will be left unset.

You may want to look into a relational database such as MySQL which is very easy to implement with php.